# Email not rendering properly

Tags: email, gmail, nodemailer

I am currently using the [NodeMailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) module to send emails from a gmail account. What I would like is to send regular html with styled attributes however nothing is styled properly except for fonts and their colors. I am using inline styles and have tried two clients outlook and gmail.

Here is the html I am sending

```
<div style="background:cornflowerblue">
Hello there!
</div>
```

while I've received much more complex html from campaigns that render just fine. I checked the mime type of my email and compared it to the others. Mine is `text/html` and theirs is `multipart/alternative` which I believe is for attachments while they are not sending any. Could this be problem or is there something else I must do?

Comment: `cornflowerblue` will obviously not render if it's not part of the email

Comment: I also tried #000. It just seems to me like the issue is not about the content (although I might be wrong) but about the underlying configurations/process.